# Can't change the screen brightness - Macbook a1342 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brightness, macbook-pro

I'm using Macbook a1342 with Ubuntu 18.04. I made the upgrade from 16.04 LTS.

After the update, along other issues I'm trying to fix, I can't change the screen brightness.

I could do it before. How do I solve this problem?

```
$ ll /sys/class/*/*/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:22 /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input17::capslock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input17::compose/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input17::kana/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input17::numlock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input17::scrolllock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input5::compose/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input5::kana/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input5::numlock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input7::capslock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input7::compose/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input7::kana/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input7::numlock/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 lip  6 19:41 /sys/class/leds/input7::scrolllock/brightness
```

Comment: To give us information can you open the terminal and run `ll /sys/class/*/*/brightness` then paste the output into your question. Caveat: the last time I used a MacIntosh was in 1984 so it will probably be someone else solving the problem.